# How to get a list of months by giving two days of a year?

Tags: sml

I have a function named `month_range` that takes two days of a year as input (e.g., 65 and 128, assuming the year has 365 days) and returns a list with the number of the month that the days from day1 through day2 belongs to.

The size of list must be "day2 - day1 + 1".

Example : month_range(25,35) should return : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]

I wrote the following code

```
fun month_range (day1:int,day2:int) =
    let
      val month_days= [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
      fun what_month(day :int) =
          let
            fun aux(sum :int,  numbers: int list) =
                let
                  val numbers_tail = tl numbers
                in
                  if sum <= (hd numbers)
                  then 1
                  else
                    1 + aux(sum, (hd numbers + hd numbers_tail)
                            :: (tl numbers_tail))
                end
          in
            aux(day, month_days)
          end
    in
      if (day1>day2)
      then []
      else what_month(day1) @ what_month(day1 + 1)@::what_month(day2)
    end
```

But it gives me the following error

```
/tmp/emacs-region5156f3r:21.51-21.54 Error: unbound variable or constructor: @::
/tmp/emacs-region5156f3r:21.12-21.70 Error: operator is not a function [literal]
  operator: int
  in expression:
    (what_month (day1 + 1)) <errorvar>
/tmp/emacs-region5156f3r:21.12-21.70 Error: operator and operand don't agree [literal]
  operator domain: 'Z list * 'Z list
  operand:         int * _
  in expression:
    what_month day1 @ (((what_month <exp>) <errorvar>) what_month) day2

uncaught exception Error
  raised at: ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:296.17-296.20
```

Comment: Please format your code when adding it, and always put in error messages as well.

Comment: OK, Jes... I'll do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off you can see from the error message, that you are using `@::`, which doesn't really make any sense.

You most likely have made the function `what_month` for another assignment, so there is no reason for putting it inside a let-expression.

Now if we simplify your code a bit

```
val month_days= [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
fun what_month(day :int) =
    let
      fun aux(sum :int,  numbers: int list) =
          let
            val numbers_tail = tl numbers
          in
            if sum <= (hd numbers)
            then 1
            else
              1 + aux(sum, (hd numbers + hd numbers_tail)::(tl numbers_tail))
          end
    in
      aux(day, month_days)
    end


fun month_range (day1:int,day2:int) =
      if (day1>day2)
      then []
      else what_month(day1)
```

then we will see that it still doesn't type. This is because the type of the `what_month` function is `int -> int`, however your if-expression inside the body of `month_range` returns a list in the then branch, then you must also return a list in the else branch. We will fix that.

Currently the function only returns the number of the month that day1 belongs to (theoretically, as is doesn't type yet). We wan't it to return a list for all the days day1 ... day2.
This is where recursion comes in. If we return `what_month(day1)` concatenated with a recursive call to `month_range( day1 + 1, day2)` then we will end up building up a list

```
what_month(day1) :: what_month(day1 + 1) :: what_month(day1 + 1 + 1) ...
```

and since you return the empty list, when you reach the condition `day1 > day2`, the recursion will give you a result like this

```
what_month(day1) :: what_month(day1 + 1) :: what_month(day1 + 1 + 1)  :: ...
                 :: what_month(day2) ::[]
```

The resulting code looks like this

```
fun month_range (day1:int,day2:int) =
    if (day1>day2)
    then []
    else what_month(day1) :: month_range(day1 + 1, day2)

- month_range(25,35);
val it = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2] : int list
```